# Git is not tracking files anymore

Tags: bash, git, shell, visual-studio-code, github

Hello I have a problem since this afternoon. I am not using git very deeply so I just use `git add` `git commit` and `git push` basically but  when I wanted to commit my changes I made a `git status` to check and every file was untracked.

[image: git status result :]

The problem is that even if I use `git add .` everything will be tracked again but then  if I wait a few seconds everything returns to untracked.

In vsc my branch is not called `main`anymore but `main +` see the screenshot under :

[image: vsc screenshot]

[image: vsc screenshot 2 :]

I don't know how this happened I did not try tricky manipulations ;) if you have any idea to fix it or if you need more information tell me

Comment: Where do you see that "everything is untracked"?

Comment: I don't see that a branch is called `main +` in any screenshot.

Comment: Is your repository stored in any kind of unusual file system, like a directory controlled by a cloud syncing service (e.g., Dropbox or iCloud), or a network file system?  Do you see this problem if you quit your editor and retry the `git add .` command?  Do you have any other processes running that might modify the repository?

Comment: @mkrieger1 when I use git status. every file or folder is in red and even after using git add it is still in red.

Comment: @bk2204 Yes my folder is synced with iCloud. I tried after closing vsc it is the same problem I can add and it is working but after a few seconds if I execute git status everything is deleted.

Comment: @bk2204 After restarting vsc I tried to execute  `git add` again and this time was definitive. now it is committed and pushed but I still don't understand what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a cloud syncing service to store your code, in this case iCloud.  As you've noticed, that can cause odd behaviour where data is changed in ways you didn't expect, and it can also cause corruption.

The reason that occurs is that cloud syncing services sync file by file and can reorder or roll back individual file operations.  Git writes files in a very particular order and requires that to maintain data integrity, but cloud syncing services don't know that and don't follow the same order of operations.  In this case, iCloud is probably rolling back your index without your consent.

You should move your repository outside of any directory synced by a cloud syncing service, and this problem will go away.  You should also run `git fsck` to verify that the repository is intact.  Dangling objects are fine, but other problems indicate corruption that you'll need to fix by restoring from another copy.

Comment: ok thanks I moved it out of the synced folder. and I ran `git fsck` everything sounds good.